# What is this PA native shrub?

Tags: identification

[image]

I purchased this shrub at a PA native plant sale, but I lost the information tag for it and the receipt. What is it?

Comment: Really need more pictures.  My first impression is a lilac; Syringa vulgaris.

Comment: Pretty sure I didn't buy a lilac. I had a list of native shrubs including shrubs  like sweet spire, button bush, elderberry, summer sweet, chokeberry, etc

Comment: It is not Elderberry, Clethera, Chokeberry, Sweet Spire...perhaps button bush or rather Cephalanthus occidentalis as it is opposite leaves, entire margins...but I really have a hard time without scale.  Need more pictures.